# How to mock an Awaitable in Python tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-asyncio, python-mock

I'm wondering if there's a way to easily mock an `Awaitable` object for python tests. I know how to use `AsyncMock`s to create mocks which mirror coroutines (i.e. will return `Awaitable` objects from method calls), but am running into a bit of problem when trying to mock an `Awaitable` directly.

Here's an example:

```py
import unittest
from asyncio import Task
from typing import Any
from unittest import IsolatedAsyncioTestCase
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock


async def function_using_awaitable(task: Task) -> Any:
    await task
    return task.result()

class TestFunction(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def test_function_using_awaitable(self):
        mock_task = AsyncMock(spec=Task)

        result = await function_using_awaitable(mock_task)

        mock_task.assert_awaited_once()
        assert result == mock_task.result.return_value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

which throws up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File ..., line 9, in function_using_awaitable
    await task
TypeError: object AsyncMock can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Digging into the Python docs it looks like the `__await__` magic method is one of the few that isn't supported in mocks so wondering how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to just extend the AsyncMock to be an awaitable mock object, adding **await**. In code, that could look like

```py
from typing import Iterator, Any

async def function_using_awaitable(task: Task) -> Any:
    await task
    return task.result()

class AwaitableMock(AsyncMock):
    def __await__(self) -> Iterator[Any]:
        self.await_count += 1
        return iter([])

class TestFunction(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def test_function_using_awaitable(self):
        mock_task = AwaitableMock(spec=Task)

        result = await function_using_awaitable(mock_task)

        mock_task.assert_awaited_once()
        assert result == mock_task.result.return_value
```

Comment: This works great; had been messing around with manually implementing the `__await__` method but didn't realise I could interact with the internal `AsyncMock` machinery in that way.